# Should high rep users be allowed to choose an answer to an very old unanswered question?

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer, unanswered-questions

Should users with high enough reputation be allowed to choose an answer to an very old unanswered question ? Only if one of the answer is obviously correct (left to the good judgment of the user) and if the author hasn't shown up in a real long time (this verification could be easily coded).

Comment: Has been asked in several variations, many times. I'm too lazy to look for the most relevant one right now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Upvoting is more than fine. An Accepted Answer should stick to the OP's discretion. They are the one asking the question, and it is their decision upon which is the best. Nobody else can really decide that for them (I am not a fan of the auto-accepted answer on bounty questions either).

Comment: Even if it's been 2 years since the user last logged ?

Comment: @Silence: Lies! The site's only been around for a year! And yes, even then :)

Comment: @silence - if it has been more than 3 months since the user logged in, then afaik their account gets deleted, so they will *never* be able to accept the answer :(

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so. Up-votes should be adequate.

If anything, perhaps SO should routinely email people to let them know they've got a question over 10 days old with x-answers. They can "remind me later" or "don't remind me."

Comment: Probably 2 days after the question is asked. Then they can also notify the user that they could place a bounty on their question.

Answer (score 0):

### I think they should be able to,  ...

<sub>... if they were the one that asked the question.</sub>